# Is there a way to set notepad++ to track which function views are minimized?

Tags: notepad++

In notepad++, during the course of working on some code (usually python), I often minimize the views of functions with the +/- icon next to the lines numbers, so that only the first line of each function definition is shown (i.e. `def [function name] (...):`). However, when I close notepad++ and restart it, all of the views of the functions are maximized again, such that all of the code of each function is displayed.

Is there a way to set notepad++ to remember which function definition views are minimized, so that when the program is restarted, minimized views remain as such? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, notepad++ doesn't save metadata on a file. So when you open a file all it have is the content of the file. And you definitively don't want notepad++ to dirty your files with is data (like which function is minimize, because other programs won't know how to "eat" it.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any plugin for notepad++ that adds metadata tracking functionality, and thus, could implement the functionality about which I inquired above? It would be quite convenient!

Comment: Thanks. For that matter, an option to minimize or maximize all function definition views in a file would be convenient as well, and would not require metadata tracking of any sort. Maybe I'll look into writing a plugin for that when I have a moment.

Comment: @Lamps1829: that you have by default. `Alt + 0` is Fold all. and `Alt + X` while  `1 <= X <=8` is Fold in level `X`.